# Unable to install pgAdmin 4 in ubuntu 21.10

Tags: ubuntu, pgadmin-4

I am facing some issues when I tried to install pgAdmin4 in the latest ubuntu version 21.10.

I have Installed the public key for the repository using following command

```
sudo curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add
```

But when I tried to create the repository configuration file using the following command I am getting an error mentioned below.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
  404  Not Found [IP: 2604:1380:2000:7501::69 443]
Hit:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,972 B]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,008 B]
Reading package lists... Done       
E: The repository 'https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/impish pgadmin4 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Alternative application name: dbeaver 
Alternative application link: https://dbeaver.io/download/
Thank you.

Comment: I think you should post this question on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or superuser, it is not programing related.

Comment: It seems Ubuntu 21.10 is not supported yet

```
DEBs for various Debian and Ubuntu versions are available from the pgAdmin APT repository. The following platforms are supported:

Debian 9 (Stretch, up to v5.3), 10 (Buster), 11 (Bullseye/testing, from v4.30)
Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial, up to v4.30), 18.04 (Bionic), 19.10 (Eoan, up to v4.29), 20.04 (Focal), 20.10 (Groovy, from v4.30), 21.04 (Hirsute, from v5.3)
```
Source: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with **hirsute** :

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/hirsute pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
```

Comment: Not working : NO_PUBKEY 8881B2A8210976F2

Comment: ^ You need to get the `asc` key and `apt-key add` it. For example, `wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -`